# Bootstrap 3.3.7 : col-xs is uneffective

Tags: html, spacing

I have an [index of articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLWVa.png) on the webpage, but the bootstrap should extend the content on 10 columns because of the [col-xs-10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Zur.png) class.

The offset is correctly set by Bootstrap, there are 2 columns before the content starts.

Maybe the problem is not about Bootstrap but CSS, I can't say I'm just learning.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The `table` has an automatic width. Try adding a `table` class to use the Bootstrap style table (which is 100% wide). So `<table class="table">`.

Comment: It's going too far, to the very edge of the window.
Sure I can modify the width in css file now, but it feels akward.

Anyway, because of you I tried to add "col-xs-8" to the table element, and it looks good !

Thank you very much !

Comment: It sounds like your `row` needs to be in a `container`, but it’s impossible to know for sure because I can’t see the markup in its entirety. Good luck!

Comment: Adding a div container only move the whole thing to the right.
I'll probably stick to the col-xs on table element, it looks ok !

Answer (score 0):

Please add like this where you added class="col-xs-10" . Just replace that with class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10"

Comment: Since Bootstrap works mobile-first, this would do nothing. `col-xs-10` automatically cascades to all larger breakpoints as long as it’s not explicitly overridden.